# How do I compare two columns in excel

Tags: excel

I wanted to compare two columns in excel , first column has 9 digit number and second column has 10 digit number, if 9 digit number of first column is equals to the 9 digit of second column number then it should return true..
for example,

```
       A                    B                     C
   123456789          1234567892                 true
```

because any 9 digits of first column are equal to any 9 digits of second column..
plz reply..
thanks in advance

Comment: Is this as in there is only a single digit in each cell and it goes from A1 through to A9? or are all digits in the same cell?

Answer (score 2):

Use the below formula:

```
=EXACT(A1,LEFT(B1,9))
```

Assuming that you always have to compare first 9 digits (from left), this will work.

How it works?

1. LEFT(B1,9) : Ignores all the extra numbers from column "B" after 9 digits.
2. Apply the "Exact" function to match the values of columns "A" and "B".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If it's always numeric values (numbers) of `X` and `X + 1` digits you're comparing (9 digits to 10, or 10 digits to 11, or 4 digits to 5), you can use integer division and `IF`, dividing the larger value by 10, converting to an integer, and comparing the result to the smaller value.

```
=IF(INT(A1 / 10) = B1, "True", "False")
```

[image: Graphic of results of above formula in Excel]

If case of the true/false doesn't matter, and you can accept TRUE/FALSE, you can remove the call to `IF`:

```
=INT(A1 / 10) = B1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,9)=LEFT(B1,9),"true","false")
```

This formula would be placed in A3 to evaluate a nine digit number in A1 and a ten digit number in A2. If you need to also match the other way (exclude the first number instead of the last) you could use:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A1,9)=LEFT(B1,9),RIGHT(A1,9)=RIGHT(B1,9)),"true","false")
```

I tested these in MS Excel 2010 and they both work.

LEFT takes items from the left side of the cell up to the number specified. RIGHT does the same from the other direction.

Comment: For simplicity's sake, you don't have to do it as an `IF` - i.e. in the first instance `=LEFT(A1,9)=LEFT(B1,9)` will work.

Comment: But if he wants the text, you need the IF to supply the result based on the condition.

Comment: `=LEFT(A1,9)=LEFT(B1,9)` resolves to Boolean `TRUE` or `FALSE` -- so if that's good enough then that will do it. But yes, if he definitely wants "true" and "false" as text only, then he'll need the `IF`.